# Ellipsoidal Coordinates Geometrically

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is there a quick, geometric, way of writing down (the square root of?) the Cartesian coordinates

$$\begin{align}
x^2 &= (a^2+\xi)(a^2+\eta)(a^2+\zeta)/(b^2-a^2)(c^2-a^2)\\
y^2 &= (b^2+\xi)(b^2+\eta)(b^2+\zeta)/(a^2-b^2)(c^2-b^2)\\
z^2 &= (c^2+\xi)(c^2+\eta)(c^2+\zeta)/(a^2-c^2)(b^2-c^2).
\end{align}$$

of the [ellipsoidal coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfocalEllipsoidalCoordinates.html) by drawing a picture, analogous to the way one derives the Cartesian components of the spherical system by drawing a circle and projecting:

[image]

It seems as though there is a trigonometric method for [the special case of oblate-spheroidal coordinates](https://geodesy.curtin.edu.au/local/docs/1Featherstone295.pdf)

[image]

[image]

(Also [here](http://books.google.ie/books?id=KovMAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&dq=%22ellipsoidal%20coordinates%22%20geodetic&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q=%22ellipsoidal%20coordinates%22%20geodetic&f=false)), so maybe this will help in the quest for ending up with the Cartesian $x^2$ etc... given above.